# How can I identify DirectShowNet Filter Pins

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

Im trying to implement a graphedit filter file i created. I am using 3ivx to encode and compress a video then save it to .mp4.

in my graphedit file i have:

```
Mpeg4s Decoder DMO (out0) -> (XForm In) 3ivx MPEG-4 Video Encoder (XForm Out)->
```

However when i put this to code, the pin (XForm In) and (XForm Out) cant be found, and therefor wont connect.

I added the running graph to DsRot to display the current graph and it showed the filter with (XForm In) and (XForm Out) pins unconnected.

I called

```
IEnumPins pinsx;
filter.EnumPins( out pinsx );
```

to try and get what pins are available but it doesnt store the names in IEnumPins, it stores object.

How can i find the pins associated with this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `FindPinByDirection` function at [Splicer.Utilities.FilterGraphTools (codeplex)](https://splicer.svn.codeplex.com/svn/src/Splicer/Utilities/FilterGraphTools.cs).

There is also a ConnectFilters function, which you probably can use:

```
public static void ConnectFilters(IGraphBuilder graphBuilder, 
            IBaseFilter upFilter, IBaseFilter downFilter, 
            bool useIntelligentConnect)
```